# Show linear independence of $\{1, \cos x, \sin x\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

Linear independence of $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given as
$$a+\cos(x)b+\sin(x)c=0$$
First I choose $x=-\frac{\pi}{2}$. I get
$$a+0b-1c=0\iff a=c$$
Then I choose $x=\pi$. I get
$$a-b+0c=0\iff a=b$$
We have that events $(\cos(x)=0\cap \sin(x)=0)=\emptyset$ as they are disjoint events, so we cannot conclude yet that $a=0$ must be true. If we use that $a=b=c$, we have:
$$a+\cos(x)b+\sin(x)c=a+\cos(x)a+\sin(x)a=0\iff 1+\cos(x)+\sin(x)=0\iff x=\pi\vee x=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
For $x\neq\pi$ and $x\neq-\frac{\pi}{2}$ then $a=b=c=0$ for the equation to be true.

Is this a proper way of showing that they are linear independent?

Comment: yes, it is good.

Comment: If you want a more elaborated way, try to multiply by $1,sin(x),cos(x)$ and then integrate over $[-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Thank you.

Comment: As long $1 + \cos x + \sin x$ isn't identically $0$, you should be good

Answer (score 2):

taking $x=0$ we get
$$a+b=0 \tag{1}$$
for $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ we get $$a+c=0 \tag{2}$$
and setting $x=\pi$ we get
$$a-b=0 \tag{3}$$
adding $(1)$ and $(3)$ together we get
$$a=0$$ and thus from $(1)$ $$b=0$$ and from $(2)$ $$c=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's good, but using also $x=0$ is simpler.

For a different approach, differentiate twice and evaluate the three expressions at $0$:
\begin{gather}
a+b\cos0+c\sin0=0\\
-b\sin0+c\cos0=0\\
-b\cos0-c\sin0=0
\end{gather}

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a different approach, suppose $a+b\cos x+c\sin x=0$ for all $x$.  Without loss of generality, we can assume $b\ge0$.  If $b^2+c^2\not=0$, then 
$$x=\arcsin\left({c\over\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}\right)\implies a+\sqrt{b^2+c^2}=0$$
while
$$x=\arcsin\left({c\over\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}\right)+\pi\implies a-\sqrt{b^2+c^2}=0$$
which together imply $b^2+c^2=0$, a contradiction. So we must have $b=c=0$, which implies $a=0$ as well.